# Model theory: Find an example for an infinite structure with only finite substructures

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory

So I tried solving this for a long time: Find an example for an infinite structure with only finite substructures.

So I tried looking at group signatures and infinite groups, but couldn't find an example that I was taught at my Abstract Algebra course that I could use - so I can't actually justify those examples.

Any assistance would be great! Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. The ring of integers considered as a structure for the signature $(0, 1, -, +, \times)$ has no proper substructures.

Comment: Just a direction I had in mind. Any example for an inifinte structure, with finite substructures only will work here

Comment: You missed the point that "no proper substructures" implies "only finite substructures".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S=\{+,f,0\}$ and $\mathfrak{A}$ be the S-structure $(\mathbb{N},0, +_\mathbb{N}, f^\mathfrak{A})$, where $f^\mathfrak{A}(0)=0$ and $f^\mathfrak{A}(n)=1$ for $n>0$

Now the only proper substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$ is $(\{0\}, 0, +_\mathbb{N}\restriction_{\{0\}\times \{0\}}, f^\mathfrak{A}\restriction_{\{0\}})$ which is finite.

Comment: Seems so obvious now! Thank you.